# Spring boot application POST request not works and not update the database

Tags: json, spring, post, intellij-idea, postman

I have java Spring Boot application. When I’m sending data POST request through POSTman. JSONObject cannot be returned, POSTman showing {"false"}

This is my controller, 
package com.lagoma.demo.controller;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")

public class User {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<UserModel> getUsers() {
        return userService.getUsers();


    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get")
    public UserModel getOneUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "00") int id) {
        return userService.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
    public boolean updateUser(@RequestBody UserModel userModel){
        return userService.updateUser(userModel);
    }
```

Comment: What is you problem really, user not saving or user is not returning ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Controller can't return primitive type or its wrapper .

You need to return some object.

If you dont have any object in scope, returning a `Map` will also do.

Change your updateUser to something like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
public Map<String, Boolean> updateUser(@RequestBody UserModel userModel){
    return Collections.singletonMap("result", userService.updateUser(userModel));
}
```

or with a Object

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
public User updateUser(@RequestBody UserModel userModel){
    // assuming userService.updateUser will return User object
    User user = userService.updateUser(userModel); 
    return user;
}
```